# parse fix length text file with XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt

I have some fix length text files to process and the outout should be a strucutred XML file. The format of these text files is specified in XML.

The tricy parts are:

- The format specification contains nested structure (a `StructFormat` element can contains `StructFormat`)
- a structure can be repeated (use attribute `repeat` of StructFormat, for example `repeat='4'`).

Here is an example of the format specification:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<MessageFormat name='NewMessageFormat' version='2.02'>
<FieldFormat name='G-TRA-MESSAGE-ID' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='18' strlenInChars='y' trimLeading=' ' trimTrailing=' '/>
    <StructFormat name='G-TAFT-HEAD-DAT' delimOptional='y'>
        <FieldFormat name='G-AFT-FIP-DATUM' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='10' strlenInChars='y' trimLeading=' ' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='G-AFT-FIP-ZEIT' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='8' strlenInChars='y' trimLeading=' ' trimTrailing=' '/>
    </StructFormat>
    <StructFormat name='G-TAFT-KUNDEN' delimOptional='y' repeat='2'>
        <FieldFormat name='G-AKU-LDSGVNR' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='6' strlenInChars='y' trimLeading=' ' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='G-AKU-KDSGVNR' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='10' strlenInChars='y' trimLeading=' ' trimTrailing=' '/>
    </StructFormat>
    <StructFormat name='G-TFGB-WGN-AN-LB' delimOptional='y' repeat='3'>
        <FieldFormat name='G-ZA-WGN-FUNK-CODE' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='1' strlenInChars='y' trimLeading=' ' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='G-FGB-WGN-RIV-CODE' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='2' strlenInChars='y' pad='0' padType='leading' trimLeading=' ' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <StructFormat name='G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD' delimOptional='y' repeat='5'>
            <FieldFormat name='G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='2' strlenInChars='y' trimLeading=' ' trimTrailing=' '/>
        </StructFormat>
        <StructFormat name='G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB' delimOptional='y' repeat='4'>
            <FieldFormat name='G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='4' strlenInChars='y' trimLeading=' ' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='4' strlenInChars='y' trimLeading=' ' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='4' strlenInChars='y' trimLeading=' ' trimTrailing=' '/>
        </StructFormat>
        <FieldFormat name='G-FBD-PRIO-KENNZ' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='1' strlenInChars='y' trimLeading=' ' trimTrailing=' '/>
    </StructFormat>
    </MessageFormat>
```

And a text sample:

```
G-TRA-MESSAGE-ID  G-AFT-FIP-G-AFT-FIG-AKU-G-AKU-KDSGG-AKU-G-AKU-KDSGGG-G-G-G-G-G-G-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGGGG-G-G-G-G-G-G-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGGGG-G-G-G-G-G-G-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG-FGG
```

So the expectd output should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NewMessageFormat>
<G-TRA-MESSAGE-ID>G-TRA-MESSAGE-ID</G-TRA-MESSAGE-ID>
<G-TAFT-HEAD-DAT>
    <G-AFT-FIP-DATUM>G-AFT-FIP-</G-AFT-FIP-DATUM>
    <G-AFT-FIP-ZEIT>G-AFT-FI</G-AFT-FIP-ZEIT>
</G-TAFT-HEAD-DAT>
<G-TAFT-KUNDEN>
    <G-AKU-LDSGVNR>G-AKU-</G-AKU-LDSGVNR>
    <G-AKU-KDSGVNR>G-AKU-KDSG</G-AKU-KDSGVNR>
</G-TAFT-KUNDEN>
<G-TAFT-KUNDEN>
    <G-AKU-LDSGVNR>G-AKU-</G-AKU-LDSGVNR>
    <G-AKU-KDSGVNR>G-AKU-KDSG</G-AKU-KDSGVNR>
</G-TAFT-KUNDEN>
<G-TFGB-WGN-AN-LB>
    <G-ZA-WGN-FUNK-CODE>G</G-ZA-WGN-FUNK-CODE>
    <G-FGB-WGN-RIV-CODE>G-</G-FGB-WGN-RIV-CODE>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>G-</G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    </G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>G-</G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    </G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>G-</G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    </G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>G-</G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    </G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>G-</G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    </G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>
    </G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>
    </G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>
    </G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>
    </G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-FBD-PRIO-KENNZ>G</G-FBD-PRIO-KENNZ>
</G-TFGB-WGN-AN-LB>
<G-TFGB-WGN-AN-LB>
    <G-ZA-WGN-FUNK-CODE>G</G-ZA-WGN-FUNK-CODE>
    <G-FGB-WGN-RIV-CODE>G-</G-FGB-WGN-RIV-CODE>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>G-</G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    </G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>G-</G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    </G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>G-</G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    </G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>G-</G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    </G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>G-</G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    </G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>
    </G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>
    </G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>
    </G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>
    </G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-FBD-PRIO-KENNZ>G</G-FBD-PRIO-KENNZ>
</G-TFGB-WGN-AN-LB>
<G-TFGB-WGN-AN-LB>
    <G-ZA-WGN-FUNK-CODE>G</G-ZA-WGN-FUNK-CODE>
    <G-FGB-WGN-RIV-CODE>G-</G-FGB-WGN-RIV-CODE>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>G-</G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    </G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>G-</G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    </G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>G-</G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    </G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>G-</G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    </G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>G-</G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    </G-FSB-SONDERBEH-CD>
    <G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>
    </G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>
    </G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>
    </G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-1>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-2>
    <G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>G-FG</G-FGB-GGT-ZETT-NR-3>
    </G-TFGB-GUT-AN-LB>
    <G-FBD-PRIO-KENNZ>G</G-FBD-PRIO-KENNZ>
</G-TFGB-WGN-AN-LB>
</NewMessageFormat>
```

My approach is use the XML format specification as XML source and text is then passed as string parameter to XLST stylesheet and use built-in XSLT template to process each element node. Here is my stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?altova_samplexml file:///D:/Entwicklung/xslt/Test_MFL.xml?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:param name="text"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="element()"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="StructFormat_withoutRepeat" match="StructFormat">
    <xsl:element name="{./@name}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="element()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="StructFormat" match="StructFormat[@repeat]">
    <xsl:variable name="repeat" select="./@repeat"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Name" select="current()/@name"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to $repeat">
        <xsl:element name="{$Name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="element()"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <!--<xsl:call-template name="StructFormat_withoutRepeat"/>-->
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="FieldFormat" match="FieldFormat">
    <xsl:variable name="fieldName" select="./@name"/>
    <xsl:element name="{./@name}">
        <xsl:value-of select="fn:substring($text,(/MessageFormat//FieldFormat[./@name = $fieldName]/preceding::FieldFormat/@length),  ./@length)"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="element()"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However it doesn't work for the repeated strcuture. The problem is in lines:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to $repeat">
        <xsl:element name="{$Name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="element()"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <!--<xsl:call-template name="StructFormat_withoutRepeat"/>-->
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Can someone please give me some idea how to resolve this problem?

Thanks a lot!
Dingjun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the child elements of the context node outside of the `for-each` over the sequence of numbers you need to store it in a variable e.g. `<xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>` before the `for-each` and then use `<xsl:apply-templates select="$this/element()"/>` inside of the `for-each`.

To deal with repeated elements, I would think that a two step approach simplifies that task, in a first step (in a a separate mode) I would transform each `struct[@repeat]` int the corresponding number of repeated `struct` elements, then I would process that result and then it should be simply a task of computing the preceding lengths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="text" as="xs:string">1234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345</xsl:param>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode name="unroll" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="struct[@repeat]" mode="unroll">
      <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
      <xsl:for-each select="1 to @repeat">
          <xsl:copy select="$this">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @repeat, node()" mode="#current"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="complete-struct">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="unroll"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$complete-struct/*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="struct">
      <xsl:element name="{@name}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="field">
      <xsl:element name="{@name}">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring($text, 1 + sum(preceding::field/@length), @length)"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaGj/4 with XSLT 3 for a simplified structure but should be doable in XSLT as well: http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/jyH9rLS which does

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:param name="text" as="xs:string">1234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345</xsl:param>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="unroll">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="struct[@repeat]" mode="unroll">
      <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
      <xsl:for-each select="1 to @repeat">
          <xsl:element name="{name($this)}" namespace="{namespace-uri($this)}">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="$this/(@* except @repeat, node())" mode="#current"/>
          </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="complete-struct">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="unroll"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$complete-struct/*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="struct">
      <xsl:element name="{@name}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="field">
      <xsl:element name="{@name}">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring($text, 1 + sum(preceding::field/@length), @length)"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

I have not understood and taken into account the other attributes like `delimOptional` as I am not sure what they signify and how they have to be taken into account the right position to extract.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With your hint I can generate the correct structure hierachy, however I still don't have the correct start posistion for deep nested structure.

Comment: However I still don't have the correct start posistion for deep nested structure.
My code is here  [http://xsltransform.net/3MP2uBb](http://xsltransform.net/3MP2uBb). In the output is start position on line 19 already wrong, and on line 53 and afterwards are also wrong.

To get the start position of one FieldFormat element, I tried to devide them into two groups, one for preceding Fieldformat elements sharing the parent (`./preceding-sibling::FieldFormat`) , and one for preceding, which doesn't share the same parent of context node (`../preceding::FieldFormat`).

Comment: I have not understood your complete XML format with the various attributes, if the `length` attributes can simply be added up for any preceding elements then I think the edit of my answer with a two step transformation that first transforms any `@repeat`ed structure into the corresponding number of structures allows an easy computation of the values. But it is difficult to tell with the complex input you have provided to tell whether that meets your requirements. If not, you might want to start with a new question with a clearer description of what all those attributes mean.

Comment: Thank you very much for the example. It's much easier to get desired output when using two steps transformation. It did really help me a lot! 
Vielen Dank!

Comment: I used the script to process a real test file with 30913 characters. I tested with XML Spy 2019 Professional and it took quite long,  about 20 seconds. Is there a way to somehow improve a little? How can I find out, which template takes most of time. I guess `sum(preceding::field/@length)` consums quite a lot time.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know whether XML Spy has some sort of profiler that can help with performance diagnostics. Using `preceding::field` is likely to be expensive, I agree. I am not sure whether using some sort of sibling recursion or (if you have XSLT 3) the use of `xsl:iterate` would perform better, you might want to ask a new question on that. As there is an open-source edition of Saxon 9.8 or 9.9 HE which also implements XSLT 2 and 3, you could, for a comparison, also try how it performs on the given problem.

Comment: I was also wondering whether `xsl:analyze-string` could help but given the nested structure of your format description I don't see an easy and straight-forward way and for sure can't judge whether it performs better.